# Keep duplicate values in dict when updated

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I am using the following code to convert a dict to json and send this to processing by javascript. 
the code reads from an excel file and updates the nested_dict.
the issue I have is when there are 2 similar values in the excel spreadsheet, obviously the dict once updated will ignore the earlier value.

How am I able to keep all duplicates please, see example of nested_dict below.

**Code:**

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(offer_path)
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)
nested_dict = {}
nested_dict["Design_Lump_Sum"] = {}
#print nested_dict
for i in range(12,19):
    design_cells = first_sheet.row_slice(rowx=i, start_colx=2, end_colx=4)
    if str(design_cells[0].value) and str(design_cells[1].value):
        if design_cells[1].value >0 :
            nested_dict["Design_Lump_Sum"].update({str(design_cells[0].value) : str(design_cells[1].value)})


nested_dict["Capex_Lump_Sum"] = {}
for i in range(22,155):
    capex_cells = first_sheet.row_slice(rowx=i, start_colx=2, end_colx=4)
    if str(capex_cells[0].value) and str(capex_cells[1].value):
        if capex_cells[1].value >0 : 
            nested_dict["Capex_Lump_Sum"].update({str(capex_cells[0].value) : str(capex_cells[1].value)})

nested_dict["Opex_Lump_Sum"] = {}
for i in range(157,175):
    Opex_cells = first_sheet.row_slice(rowx=i, start_colx=2, end_colx=4)
    if str(Opex_cells[0].value) and str(Opex_cells[1].value):
        if Opex_cells[1].value >0 : 
            nested_dict["Opex_Lump_Sum"].update({str(Opex_cells[0].value) : str(Opex_cells[1].value)})

nested_dict["Provisional_Sum"] = {}
for i in range(176,198):
    Provisional_cells = first_sheet.row_slice(rowx=i, start_colx=2, end_colx=4)
    if str(Provisional_cells[0].value) and str(Provisional_cells[1].value):
        if Provisional_cells[1].value >0 or Provisional_cells[1].value <0:
            nested_dict["Provisional_Sum"].update({str(Provisional_cells[0].value) : str(Provisional_cells[1].value)})

nested_dict["Management_fees"] = {}
for i in range(200,209):
    Management_fees = first_sheet.row_slice(rowx=i, start_colx=2, end_colx=4)
    if str(Management_fees[0].value) and str(Management_fees[1].value):
        if Management_fees[1].value >0 :
            nested_dict["Management_fees"].update({str(Management_fees[0].value) : str(Management_fees[1].value)})

nested_dict["CSA"] = {}
for i in range(211,231):
    CSA = first_sheet.row_slice(rowx=i, start_colx=2, end_colx=4)
    if str(CSA[0].value) and str(CSA[1].value):
        if CSA[1].value >0 or CSA[1].value <0 :
            nested_dict["CSA"].update({str(CSA[0].value) : str(CSA[1].value)})

nested_dict["Total"] = {}
nested_dict["Total"].update({"sub_Total": str(first_sheet.cell(234,3))})


print  nested_dict
return json.dumps(nested_dict)
```

**List output example printed by the code below:**

> {'Management_fees': {}, 'Capex_Lump_Sum': {'Refrigerant piping':
>   '48040.447', 'Preparation of Mops': '2137.681', 'Labels': '653.016',
>   'Penetrations and Protection': '1535.534', 'AC Plinth and Trays':
>   '5221.762', 'Insulated Panel Windows': '6527.794', ' MSSB':
>   '19582.199', 'Make Good Walls and Floors': '4154.696', 'Controls':
>   '24092.978', '** Building Surveyor Fee (Misc)': '7038.85', 'Project
>   Manag ement, Supervision': '38447.5', 'Painting': '9138.675',
>   'Preliminaries': '1306.032', 'Package system wiring': '16971.318',
>   'Warranty': '2610.881', 'Ductwork, Valves and Dampers': '77262.913',
>   'Unit ty pe': '89107.109', 'Structural Engineer for new unit stands':
>   '3916.913', 'Manuals': '3823.456', 'AMS and BMS works': '3916.913',
>   'Accoustic Report': '4243.421', 'Lighting': '5033.665', 'Drawings':
>   '38
>   23.456', 'Temp Cooling': '10443.524', 'Commissioning': '3263.897', 'Crane': '3003.637', 'Demolition': '26455.429', 'Fire detection and
>   Alarm FIP modifications': '3263.897', 'LSL': '1939.81059657', 'Ec
>   onomy Cycle': '23169.055'}, 'Provisional_Sum': {'Condenser Roof
>   Platform': '20000.0', 'Removal of ladder outside cable chamber exit
>   stairs': '10000.0'}, 'Opex_Lump_Sum': {}, 'CSA': {'Additional Hendry 
>   Fees': '3742.5', 'External Ladder': '10147.0', 'Asbestos removal Works
>   Total ($42,485.15)  (remainder of cost $30K under PS sum)':
>   '12485.15'}, 'Design_Lump_Sum': {'** Detailed Design': '15379.0', '*
>   * Const Stage Services': '4732.0', '** Preliminary Design': '2366.0'}, 'Total': {'sub_Total': 'number:530154.0105965699'}}

Comment: This is surely not a `list` but a `dict`.

Comment: can this be changed to list while keeping the same format? I revised the question and replace list by dict

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a "dict list"; these are two different data structures.  A **dict** does not retain duplicates, by definition, so it's unclear what you expect.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
This is not minimal code, there is no driver code (all this does is define the function and quit), and you've failed to show the input or the desired output.

Comment: Dict can only have one key one time, if you want one key to have multiple values, you have to set the values of a key to be a list or a different container that describes multiple values.

Comment: revised the question to dict. sorry for the confusion, can this be changed to list and what should i change to have the same output please